# E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException for (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, image, kotlin, gallery

I try to open image from gallery and display in Imageview in same Activty . I add permissions like **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** , **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** , **INTERNET**. when i select image from gallery and return activity it display this type of error

> 09-04 15:02:57.161 31642-31642/com.androidtutorialpoint.qrcodescanner E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20180816-160721.png (No such file or directory)

Here my code :-

1. Button click event for open gallery :-

   btn?.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
           override fun onClick(arg0: View) {

   ```
           val i = Intent(
                   Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

           startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE)
       }
   })
   ```
2. This for use display image in Imageview:-

   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

   ```
   if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
       val selectedImage = data.data
       val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

       val cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedImage!!,
               filePathColumn, null, null, null)
       cursor!!.moveToFirst()

       val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
       val picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
       cursor.close()

       val imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView
       imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file://" + picturePath))

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: you have `Uri selectedImage` -  just use it in your `ImageView`

Comment: how can i add this @pskink

Comment: by reading [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) official documentation

Comment: ok ok thank you for it@pskink

Comment: its not working @pskink

Comment: what its not working? what do you see when you call `Log.d(TAG, "uri: " + selectedImage)`?

Comment: imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/d2.jpg")) @pskink

Comment: why do you want to call `Uri.parse`? if you already have `Uri selectedImage`? what do you see when you call `Log.d(TAG, "uri: " + selectedImage)`?

Comment: i got solution for it.. ty @pskink for your help

Comment: is it not working on Oreo or above devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement for your `query()` to return a filesystem path that you can use.

Instead, pass your `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.). They can load the image into your `ImageView`, doing all of the I/O on a background thread.